# Prove that the series is continuous and differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

How to prove that the series $\sum e^{-nx+\cos(nx)}$ is defined, continuous and differentiable (with a continuous derivative) on $(a, \infty)$
for any $a > 0$.

I am good with continuity part. But how to go for differentiability ? Please help in that

Answer (score 2):

Define $f_n(x) = e^{-nx + \cos(nx)}$.  Then $$ |f_n(x)| = e^{-nx + \cos(nx)} = e^{-nx }\cdot e^{\cos(nx)} \leq e^{-nx} \cdot e \leq e^{-na}\cdot e. $$

Define $M_n := e^{-na}\cdot e$.  Then $\sum M_n = e \frac{1}{1 - e^{-a}} < \infty$.  By the [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), this implies that the series $\sum f_n(x) $ converges uniformly.  Since each $f_n$ is continuous, this them implies that the sum is continuous as well.

To show that the series is differentiable with continuous derivative you need to show that $\sum f_n'$ converges uniformly by a similar calculation using Weierstrass M-test.